# Why Object.values retains its parents' reference even if the object is cloned?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-5

Say you have an `object obj = { a : [1, 2] }` and you create a clone of it `objClone = Object.assign({}, obj)` and when you modify Object.values(objClone)[0][1], then the parent obj is also modified. Can someone explain why?

Comment: `Object.assign()` makes a **shallow copy** of the source object.

Comment: But changing Object.values(objClone)[0] doesn't change the parent object. Can you explain why @Pointy

Comment: Because `Object.values()` also makes a shallow copy.

Comment: `Object.values` returns a *new* array reference, but all the elements (shallowly copied) still refer to the original elements, thus if you mutate a value in the "copied" array it mutates the same value reference in the original array.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
let objA = { a : [1, 2] }
```

the value of `objA.a` is a reference to the array created by the array literal. So when you copy the object:

```
let objB = Object.assign({}, objA)
```

then the value of `objB.a` is a copy of the value of `objA.a`, so is a reference to the same array.

That is often referred to as a "shallow copy", that is, it's just a simple copy of the value without resolving references to copy whatever they reference.

When you do:

```
console.log(objA.a)
```

then the reference is resolved so it prints the contents of the array, not the actual value of the reference (which would be a bit useless).